# Excel 2013, searching for partial text in one cell and overwriting adjacent cell if condition is met

Tags: excel, if-statement, filtering, vba

I need to write a macro.

I've got a workbook with ~ 30000 rows (changes daily).

1. I need to search for expression "TRADE" within the strings in cells from column (A)
2. If string inside the cell contain expression TRADE I need to change string in relevant cell in column (B) (the same row) to expression "TRADEIN"
3. If condition is not met relevant cells from column (B) need to stay unchanged

---

What have I learned so far:

`Formula  =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TRADE", A1 )), 1, 2)` changes adjacent cell value accordingly ONLY if placed directly inside cell and copied down in Excel.

Problems starts when I try to have string as an outcome

`Formula: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TRADE", A1 )), "TRADEIN", "")` won't work ->error

`Formula: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TRADE", A1 )), ""TRADEIN"", "")` won't work ->error

---

Then any attempts to make my macro insert more complex formulas into cells from VBA failed i.e.:

Below works fine:

```
For i=1 to i=NumberOfRows

ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "= 2+2"

next i
```

---

Below won't work (again, formula works if placed in the cell directly):

```
For i=1 to i=NumberOfRows

ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TRADE", (i, 1)), 1, 2)"

next i
```

---

I think there's no point in listing all my failed attempts to make it work so far (loads of useless lines to read I presume) but by all means - correct me if I'm wrong.

I can't find solution as specific as my task and have got problems altering some found online whilst other won't work for me at all. Perhaps don't exactly know how to ask for what I need in the most effective way. Be very basic and try not to miss out any declarations from proposed modules/subs if you can - I'm not yet confident when it comes to using and creating objects and methods outside of a few examples I followed, or choosing/using the right type of variables with compatible methods/functions etc.

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish what you are after, as you can see in the answers below, but just so you know, if you want your formula to work in VBA, you can write this: `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""TRADE"",A" & i & ",1,2)`. Notice the open and close `"` around the quotes in `TRADE` to get VBA to recognize you want to include '"s` in the formula and how to use the `&` to wrap variables into strings.

Comment: I just want to comment that for your first question it's a well presented one..  You presented a clear question and showed the code that you've tried and couldn't get to work.  Better than a lot of first questions.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks You all for quick replies. Will sit down today to learn how to reward your efforts in line with forum rules and mechanics. In regards to solutions I should have time to check and  find out if and what works best in my case tomorrow at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VBA this is how would accomplish the goal.  This will find the last row used in column A to set the range to work through.

```
Sub test()

Dim w As Range
lrow = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
For Each w In Range("A1:A" & lrow).Cells
    If w.Value = "trade" Then
        w.Offset(0, 1).Value = "tradein"
    End If
Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You for that module, only drawback is that it will only work with exact match ("trade") and will ignore ("TRADE";"TradeIn" etc.), using asterisk doesn't seem to change anything. I can still copy For function for all possible cases (40+) and that sorts me out for now. Once again Thank you :)

Comment: Now, I have no idea why, but if I try to use the module on full file (did test it on a sample with 20 rows of data filled manually) it won't update values in column B. It does work however if I remove "SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)." from 2nd row...?

Comment: I meant: ...from 2nd line to make it look as such ->[lrow = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Count]...? Full file.xlsx has values exported from Access database query using process/code I have no access to at the moment, values in both columns seem to be strings when I look at them in full file.xlsx (MSExcel2013)

Comment: you can use `LIKE` instead of `=`.   `If w.value like "trade*"`

Comment: Sir, you are a savior. Thanx a lot. I can use it in other places where I was struggling although with much smaller amount of cases to search for. Once again thank You and have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Practice using the auto filter, once you have that worked out use the macro recorder to get a code to work on.

Select column A and the goto Data=>Filter=>text Filter=>Contains....type the word in the box to filter for.

[image]